Shared printer over WiFi through USB connected laptop
2 Dell laptops, windows 10.
Brother printer connects to one of the laptops through USB only.
Both laptops installed with Brother driver and through USB they work fine.
Both have network discovery enabled with printer sharing enabled.
Both computers able to ping each other as they are on the same WiFi network.
The printer is shared by the laptop to which the USB connected and when searched up on the other laptop over the network the printer is not dectected, again the laptops ping each other but the printer is no where to be seen, I have tried manually adding the printer, it will add but it will not print as the printer is not detected by the second laptop which is on the same Wifi network.
I want to be able to share the printer over WiFi network through the laptop, I am not concerned about security with regards to this.
I cannot use WiFi direct option because I cannot educate people enough on how to change the WiFi network in order to print.
I cannot connect my printer to the WiFi because I do not want to use an IP in the network for it.
I am fine to keep the laptop which has USB connected powered on all the time.
I want to share the printer this way, is this possible? If yes, why do you think its not working?, does the WiFi network have specific configuration where print sharing can be disabled or the protocol that runs print reports is not enabled.
Thank you, spent over 4 hours trying to figure, but no results.

Is this your personal network, or a shared/business/apartment network? Are the computers set to trust the network and/or find devices on the network? Are you signing in with the same Microsoft account on both computers, or different MS accounts, or with local-only accounts?

If you add the printer by IP address instead of name, does it work? If you ping the all-hosts multicast address 224.0.0.1 from each laptop, do they each see multiple devices, including each other, replying to the pings? Buggy Wi-Fi device often have broken multicast implementations, and broken multicast breaks service discovery.

@john Thanks, however, the person trying to print is sitting in a room across the floor.

@music2myear Business network
Yes, they are set to truct.
No, do not use Microsoft accounts, just domain sign ins and different people on both sides.

@Spiff tried to add with ip when I try to add the printer to the other laptop and it does not get detected.

If this is a business network you need to talk with the IT staff who run this network as they likely have settings in place impacting this, and will also have the correct/preferred methods of sharing this printer.

@Spiff When I ping 224.0.0.1 it does ping successfully, I do not see multiple devices but just the ping is a success, I am just pining from the cmd, let me know if I should be something different. Is there a way to test if it has broken multicast service discovery?

@music2myear I am IT, ran at deadends like these, seeing if this is even possible, I am just missing out on something to make it work, practically there should be no problems, unsure what is stopping it from even getting detected.

I think those details need to be in the question, about your being IT, about this being a business network, a domain, and all that.

@Spiff anything you could add to my questions?

@AdamH You didn't give me enough details of your multicast ping results, so I can't make progress. I think a more reliable test of my "multicast failure" hypothesis would be for you to connect both laptops to the LAN via wired Ethernet (turn off Wi-Fi on both laptops), and see if things work fine via wired Ethernet. Multicast is far FAR more reliable on wired Ethernet than on wireless, so if this works via wired Ethernet and not via Wi-Fi, it's a good indication that it's a multicast problem. Buy USB Ethernet adapters for your laptops if you need to. They're cheap and hugely useful for this.
